# How to get name in php api in android

Tags: android

In android how to get like,

```
 {
categories: [
{
id: "20",
name: "health",
created_at: "2016-07-15 10:17:51",
updated_at: "2016-07-15 10:17:51",
color: "#0d5a91",
parent_id: "0",
order: "0"
},
{
id: "21",
name: "fashion",
created_at: "2016-07-15 10:23:00",
updated_at: "2016-07-15 10:23:00",
color: "#c732bd",
parent_id: "0",
order: "0"
},
{
id: "22",
name: "people",
created_at: "2016-07-15 12:42:47",
updated_at: "2016-07-15 12:42:47",
color: "#c7323e",
parent_id: "0",
order: "0"
},
],
success: 1
}
```

Comment: First of all you need to solve to syntax problem of your api json

Comment: There are at least a billion tutorials around to fetch and parse data

Comment: what is syntax probllem buddy..? i know there is so billion tutorials around it but i need success tag and name tag...how it is possible there is not any tutorioal on internet..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Your json should be like this**

```
{
"categories":[
{
"id":"20",
"name":"health",
"created_at":"2016-07-15 10:17:51",
"updated_at":"2016-07-15 10:17:51",
"color":"#0d5a91",
"parent_id":"0",
"order":"0"
},
{
"id":"21",
"name":"fashion",
"created_at":"2016-07-15 10:23:00",
"updated_at":"2016-07-15 10:23:00",
"color":"#c732bd",
"parent_id":"0",
"order":"0"
},
{
"id":"22",
"name":"people",
"created_at":"2016-07-15 12:42:47",
"updated_at":"2016-07-15 12:42:47",
"color":"#c7323e",
"parent_id":"0",
"order":"0"
}
],
"success":1
}
```

> **Try this to get name or others**

```
 JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
    try {
    String success=String.valueOf(jsonObject.getString("success")) ;


    JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("categories");

    for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++)
    {

            JSONObject jsonCategoryObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        String name=jsonCategoryObject.getString("name");

        String id=jsonCategoryObject.getString("id");

        String created_at=jsonCategoryObject.getString("created_at");

        String updated_at=jsonCategoryObject.getString("updated_at");

        String color=jsonCategoryObject.getString("color");
        String order=jsonCategoryObject.getString("order");
        String parent_id=jsonCategoryObject.getString("parent_id");
        }
    }

    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
                String name="";
                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
                try {
                    String success=jsonObject.getString("success");
                    JSONArray array=jsonObject.getJSONArray("categories");

                    for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++) {
                        JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        name = obj.getString("name");
               }

Comment: You take the name outside the for loop check the code

Comment: Success here Integer value... take    String.valueOf(jsonObject.getString("success"))  ;

Comment: Other take 1 in double quato to response 1  "success": "1"

Comment: JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response) Aree You Pass the response in json

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the json format is wrong

```
{ 
    "categories": [ 
        { "id": "20", "name": "health", "created_at": "2016-07-15 10:17:51", "updated_at": "2016-07-15 10:17:51", "color": "#0d5a91", "parent_id": "0", "order": "0" },
        { "id": "21", "name": "fashion", "created_at": "2016-07-15 10:23:00", "updated_at": "2016-07-15 10:23:00", "color": "#c732bd", "parent_id": "0", "order": "0" },
        { "id": "22","name": "people", "created_at": "2016-07-15 12:42:47", "updated_at": "2016-07-15 12:42:47", "color": "#c7323e", "parent_id": "0", "order": "0" }
    ],
    "success": 1 
}
```

Next use

```
JSONObject response = (JsonObject) someStringValueAsResponseFromAPICall;
JSONArray array = response.optString("categories");
JSONObject innerObject = array.optJSONObject(position);
String success = response.optString("success");
```

Note: Use "opt"JSONObject/JSONArray/String instead of "get"JSONObject/JSONArray/String, this will avoid errors but lookout for null pointer exceptions